# What does 谈晋倏忽之间勾了下嘴角 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I found a novel on my Kindle (*喜欢你，我也是*) which seem like a teenage romance, and seems fairly readable and interesting.  I'm at the start, and thus far Zhang Kankan 张侃侃 and seems to have been tricked into a blind date with Tan Jin (thinking she's there to [补习](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%A1%A5%E4%B9%A0)); they're both teachers.  Currently, Tan Jin seems to be confusing her.

It has the line:

> “哦？”**谈晋倏忽之间勾了下嘴角**，“金主让你做什么就做什么，是这个意思吗？”
>   <sub>*喜欢你，我也是*</sub>

I don't understand the part in bold.  (It seems Tan Jin is also confusing me.)

> "Oh?" Tan Jin suddenly (?) [倏忽之间] hooked the corners of his mouth (?) [勾了下嘴角], "Bankroller makes you do something, you do it, is this the meaning?"

**Question**: What does 谈晋倏忽之间勾了下嘴角 mean?

Comment: "倏忽之间" means "in a very short time" or "in the twinkling of an eye".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 哦？”谈晋倏忽之间勾了下嘴角，“金主让你做什么就做什么，是这个意思吗？”

倏忽之间: suddenly

For 勾了下嘴角 you could perhaps write: 轻蔑 or 冷笑

谈晋倏忽之间勾了下嘴角，
Tan Jin suddenly snarled,

“金主让你做什么就做什么，是这个意思吗？
"If the boss wants you to do then do it, is that what you mean?"

You could replace 倏忽之间勾了下嘴角 with either: 冷笑道 or 轻蔑地说道

谈晋冷笑道， : Tan Jin, with a sarcastic smile, said,
谈晋轻蔑地说道，Tan Jin disdainfully spoke,

Answer (score 1):

勾了下嘴角 = it's just a literary expression to describe a facial expression when the speaker is about to say something sarcastic or something emotional, like in the sentence in question, “哦？谈晋倏忽之间勾了下嘴角..." = "Oh?, Tan Jin momentarily lifted the corner of his mouth..."

It's like the "raised eyebrow" while speaking indicating surprise or disapproval.

Answer (score 1):

倏忽之间 = 快速地

it is literary way to say "just in a second"
勾嘴角 is just a face expression.

you need contexts to know why he did that.